# Find difference of categorical data in r

Tags: r, categorical-data, date-difference

I am new to this website and to R language and this is my first question here :)

I am analyzing a data set of US people's salary in different years and different states (30 in total labeled as 1, 2, ..., 30). The starting year are all the same (1970) but the ending years vary (from 1990 to 2000). For each state, I wish to find the difference between the salary in the ending year and that in the starting year. I wrote the following but it does not work:

```
for (i in 1:30) {
  salarygrowth <- function(salary[state == "i", time == max(1990:2000, na.rm=FALSE)], salary[state == "i", time == 1970]) { 
  salary[state == "i", time == max(1990:2000, na.rm=FALSE)] - salary[state == "i", time == 1970]}
}
```

How could I fix and improve it so that I could the desired salary growth for each state with the year provided. 
Thanks so much in advance!

As required, the following is some data:

```
  time      state       salary
  1970        1         27890
  1971        1         28800
  1972        1         31257
  1973        1         32846
              ...
  1995        1         58934
  1970        2         26783
  1971        2         28987
              ...
  1997        2         67998
  1970        3         21349
              ...
  1992        3         56212
              ...
  2000        30        67876
```

Comment: @akrun Please see above. Thanks.

Comment: Posted a solution below.  Please check if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this using aggregate by group functions.  One option is `dplyr`.  We grup by 'state' and get the difference between 'salary' corresponding to maximum 'time' with the minimum 'time'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarise(salary = salary[which.max(time)]- salary[which.min(time)])
```

Another option if the 'time' column is not ordered, we order it by `arrange` and then use `first`, `last` to extract the first, last values of salary and take the difference.

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(state) %>%
   arrange(time) %>%
   summarise(salary=last(salary)- first(salary))
```

---

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'state', `order` by 'time', get the difference of last (`.N`) and first (`1L`) 'salary'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(time), list(salary=salary[.N]- salary[1L]), by = state]
```

---

Or if the 'time' and 'state' is ordered, we can also use `duplicated` on 'state' column to get a logical index, extract the 'salary' to get the difference.

```
 salary <- with(df1, salary[!duplicated(state, fromLast=TRUE)]-
                     salary[!duplicated(state)])
 data.frame(state=unique(df1$state), salary)
```